# Managing aws resouces not created through terraform configuration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've come across some AWS resources that were not created through my terraform configuration that I later realized I need to update. An example is cloudwatch logs where in my initial config (like lambda, db, etc...) didn't have any specification to create them.  however, later if I want to set any config for the logs Im having trouble adding those resources to my config.  I believe I need to do a `terraform import` for those resources but it essentially requires me to issue that command before the `terraform apply`.

This isn't really that clean if I have a process where I can do only one command (`terraform apply`).

Any suggestions to manage the `terraform import` as part of the config only? Like an import if not available.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you want to import some resources, without using `terraform import`?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: If it were possible to import (if not already available within my tf state) within my terraform configuration and be able to modify them would be great.

Comment: I guess you could try adding the state by hand to the tfstate file, though that sounds fraught with errors. You could set up a test set of similar resources (in a test account or somewhere like that), copy over the resource state from there and update it to match your actual resources. It's going to be yucky though

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not do that. If I have any CI/CD platforms where the data input is dynamic this gets very messy.

Comment: So what you're saying is "I can't use the correct tool for the job (`terraform import`) and I don't want to do it by hand, what should I do?"

Comment: Im saying there are some limitations with the only tool I know of and are there other tools or approaches around it.